# How do I filter a list in Haskell based on a particular elements value?

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I have a list of type Film, where Film(Director Title Year Likes Dislikes), which corresponds to Film -> String -> String -> Int -> [String] -> [String].
I also have a function that takes in the likes and dislikes lists and returns a percentage rating, as such that:

```
rating :: Likes -> Dislikes -> Int
rating likes dislikes = (((length [likes]) / ((length [dislikes]) + (length [likes]))) * 100)
```

My problem:
I cannot work out how to use `filter` to sort this list, to determine whether or not each film's rating is 75% or over.

This is my current attempt:

```
filterFilm :: Film -> Bool
filterFilm (Film t d y likes dislikes)
            | (rating likes dislikes) > 74  = True
            | otherwise                     = False

-- List film rating with and over 75%
listRating :: Database -> Database
listRating (x:xs) = filter (filterFilm x) (x:xs)
```

I get this error:

```
Cw 2018.hs:87:29: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Film -> Bool’
                  with actual type ‘Bool’
    • Possible cause: ‘filterFilm’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘(filterFilm x)’
      In the expression: filter (filterFilm x) (x : xs)
      In an equation for ‘listRating’:
          listRating (x : xs) = filter (filterFilm x) (x : xs)
   |
87 | listRating (x:xs) = filter (filterFilm x) (x:xs)    |
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `length [likes]` is always 1 because you’re passing it a list of one element, being the list `likes`. Presumably you want `length likes` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you use `filter` the wrong way. `filter` is a function that takes two parameters, the first one a predicate `a -> Bool` and the second one a list of `a`s.

Now the parameter that is passed to `listRating` is that list, so `listRating l`, and you thus call the `filter` with `filter filterFilm l`, so:

```
listRating :: Database -> Database
listRating l = filter filterFilm l
```

We can also remove the `l` parameter both in the head and body of the function, like:

```
listRating :: Database -> Database
listRating = filter filterFilm
```

Note that you can simplify your `filterFilm` function to:

```
filterFilm :: Film -> Bool
filterFilm (Film t d y likes dislikes) = rating likes dislikes > 74
```